# Passing an arraylist as a struct property from a webservice

Tags: web-services, asmx

I have a web service that sends a struct to a client program.

I need to pass an arraylist of string values as one of the properties of this struct, but by the time it gets to the client program its type is 'object'. Once it gets back to the client program, how can I convert this Object datatype back into the arraylist?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using, and I presume you mean you're using an ASMX web service?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're stuck at .NET 1.1, don't use `ArrayList`. Try returning a `List<YourStruct>` instead.

Comment: Are you serious? Which version are you using? `ArrayList` hasn't been a good idea since .NEt 1.1. The addition of generic collections in .NEt 2.0 makes `ArrayList` stupid and dangerous, and not type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I was attempting to explicitly create an arraylist and then setting it equal to the returned property from the struct; here's the correct way to do it - some weird VB implicit thingy. (sorry, never drank the VB kool-aid)

```
Dim ReturnedArrList As New ArrayList(structReturned.arrReturnedArrayList)
```

Comment: And, you should still not use `ArrayList`.